# C# element-wise difference between two lists of numbers

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, reduce

Assume

```
List<int> diff(List<int> a, List<int> b)
{ 
    // assume same length lists
    List<int> diff= new List<int>(a.Count);
    for (int i=0; i<diff.Count; ++i)
    {
        diff[i] = a[i] - b[i];
    }
    return diff;
}
```

I would like to have some kind of one-liner do the same, or something that uses a lambda, rather than re-writing all the boilerplate.

for instance, in python, this would be either

```
[ai-bi for ai,bi in zip(a,b)]
```

or even

```
np.array(a) - np.array(b)
```

---

Is there a nice way to write this in C#? All my searches find ways to remove or add list elements, but nothing about element-wise actions.

Comment: Zip is the word: `a.Zip(b, (x, y) => x - y);`

Answer (score 4):

Linq has a [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) method as well:

```
var diff = a.Zip(b, (ai, bi) => ai - bi);
```

Note that one potential bug in your code is if `b` has fewer elements than `a` then you'd get an exception when you try to access an element outside the range of `b`. `Zip` will only return items as long as *both* collections have items, which is effectively the shorter of the two collection lengths.